# How to setup Push Notification in SMP3

Tags: sap-smp

I am working on setting up push notification in SMP3. I have created an app in the cockpit and also I have set the Sender ID and API Key. But I am unable to find what to do now. Do I need to write some code in my app too? Also how to push the notification in the mobile? Is there any proper documentation for that?